# How to represent normal law and a variable intermingled?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, graphing-functions

> Let's consider that a variable y constructed from x
>
> $x_i ∈ \left\{1;3;5;7;8\right\}$
>
> $f(x_i)=2x_i+1$
>
> $y_i=f(x_i) + ε_i, ∀i∈ \left\{1;...;5\right\} $
>
> where $ε_i$ is a identically and independantly distributed random variable which follows a normal law $\mathcal{N(0,2)}$

How can I represent this on a graph?

Comment: I don't understand. What is meant by "example of a realisation for $y$"? I mean, $\epsilon_i$ can take any value in $\mathbb R$. An example of a realisation is then: $0.44$.

Comment: Yes, I think that's the point. I didn't understood very well the answer neither, I thinh the answer is giving an example of a realisation of y in order to be able to do the second question which is: "plot the corresponding scatter plot".

Comment: btw, you have also not defined $x_i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the point of this is to illustrate a linear relationship between two variables.

If $f(x)$ is linear function, that means it is on the form $f(x)=ax+b$. What will this entail in terms of the quantity $f(x_i)$? It means that if you have a plot with $x_i$-values on the $x$-axis and $f(x_i)$-values on the $y$-axis, the $f(x_i)$-values will all lie on a straight line.

Now, $y_i$ is defined as $f(x_i)$ plus some error term $\epsilon_i$, which is going to spread the $y_i$-values around the straight line in a relatively regular fashion. For examples of this, just google "linear regression plot".

Comment: Yes I understand it that way too. Do you have any tool that would help me plot it?

Comment: @colocantoine pen and paper should suffice in this case :) You have only 5 possible values of $x_i$.

Comment: okay. Even for the erratic epsilon which follow the normal law distribution? Because I have then too calculate the correlation coefficient of x and y...

Comment: @colocantoine if you need an actual simulation of $\epsilon$ then you obviously would have to use some software, but I don't think that is the point of the exercise. The correlation can be calculated analytically.

Comment: I've just done the calculation, (and edited my question) but I'm actually not sure I'm going in the good direction...
furthermore I'm not sure about my use of the Expectation properties, can you review it and tell me so?

Comment: @Marine1 this seems like an altogether new question, you should post it separately